# Chromium cannot install addons anymore

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, chromium

Chromium 55.0.2883.75-6 (debian strech) disabled all addons (they do not even appear in the extension list anymore) and even on new profiles i cannot install new ones.

My steps to reproduce:

- remove chromium profile
- visit the chrome webstore and try to install an addon, e.g. [umatrix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf?hl=en)
- confirm the `Add "uMatrix"?` dialog with "Add Extension"

Then i get a yellow bar below the bookmark bar "Installation not enabled [OK]" with an arrow pointing on the "Secure" badge of the URL-Bar.

Why is the installation disabled even on a fresh profile and the installed addons ignored on an existing profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch with --enable-remote-extensions

See here:

unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344359/after-an-upgrade-chromium-doesn-t-see-any-of-my-extensions-anymore

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. But it's strange, that i cannot even install new addons (which should be packaged by now?).